# Ошибка при подключении NuGet-пакета

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Имеется [NuGet-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETMouseProjects.ABCNET/). Он создавался со [следующей](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yPBI20Ax0aKMIOWmsQs738yRUxavgOrD) структурой. Всё, вроде бы хорошо, но при попытке подключения его к программе под `NET 4.0` вылетает ошибка:

```
Could not install package 'NETMouseProjects.ABCNET 0.0.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю почему это происходит и как исправить. Сама библиотека, как и программа, работает на 4-ом NET (я пробовал и другие версии NET - ошибка всё равно есть). Создавал я его через `nuget.exe`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваш nuget ничего в себе не содержит (нет dll), возможно вы его не правильно собираете

Comment: Странно... Я последовательно запускаю команды: nuget spec и nuget pack... nuget.exe лежит в корневой папке на уровне lib. Нажмите на вторую ссылку в первом сообщении, чтобы посмотреть что должно быть в nuget-пакете. nuget.exe сообщает, что сборка произошла успешна, но тогда почему nuget-пакет пуст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот .nuspec пакета:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>NETMouseProjects.ABCNET</id>
    <version>0.0.10-stable</version>
    <authors>NETMouse projects</authors>
    <owners>NETMouse projects</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">LGPL-3.0-only</license>
    <licenseUrl>https://licenses.nuget.org/LGPL-3.0-only</licenseUrl>
    <icon>Logo.png</icon>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/NETMouse-projects/ABCNET</projectUrl>
    <description>ABCNET - альтернатива модулю PABCSystem для всего NET.</description>
    <releaseNotes>- Batch
      - Pairwise
      - Associate
      - ZupTuple/UnzipTuple
      - SwapCols/SwapRows</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>NETMouseProjects, ABCNET</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

В нем нет ни одной библиотеки, не то что под .NET 4.0. Добавьте элемент [files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    ...
  </metadata>
  <files>
        <file src="lib\net40\*" target="lib/net40/" />        
  </files>
</package>
```

Тогда заработает. При этом библиотека должна лежать в подкаталоге `lib\net40\`. Вообще, обычно nuget pack должен сам файлы библиотек находить и генерировать files, возможно, нужно просто положить их по правильному пути.